# Permission is only granted to system app

Tags: android, eclipse, lint

I have a **System app** that uses system permissions and I have those permissions listed in the manifest. Eclipse gives the following **error** when I try to make a build(command line build works):

> Permission is only granted to system apps

I'm already aware that my app requires system permissions and it is not a problem for me because my application will be used only on rooted phones. So I want to suppress this error, anyone knows how?

**EDIT**
My project already compiles fine on command line, installs, runs etc.. My problem is about eclipse giving an error for a legit manifest file.

Comment: Did u check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9494965/603744

Comment: @AndroSelva it is unrelated, my project already compiles fine on command line, installs, runs etc.. My problem is about eclipse giving an error for a legit manifest file. IMO it should only produce a warning in this case.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

**In Eclipse:**

> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.

In the list find an entry with `ID = ProtectedPermission`. Set the Severity to something lower than Error. This way you can still compile the project using Eclipse.

**In Android Studio:**

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections

Under `Android Lint`, locate `Using system app permission`. Either uncheck the checkbox or choose a Severity lower than Error.

Comment: Thanks!  In Android Studio 1.2, I found this under File -> Settings -> _Editor_ -> Inspections.

Comment: I want to change the screen brightness programmatically. I have edited the Lint under settings. But it's throwing some security exception while trying to change the screen brightness programmatically. Anyone have any solution to implement this feature in Android 3.1 above Marshmallow, please share.

Comment: In Android Studio 2.1, Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections then expand Android > Lint > Correctness. Select "Using system app permission", change severity or uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: It was under `Android > Lint > Correctness` for me.

Answer (score 108):

To ignore this error for one instance only, add the `tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"` attribute to your permission declaration. Here is an example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

You have to add  `tools` namespace in the manifest root element

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: This is the right anwser.
Why disabling the whole inspection when it is only partially needed.
Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 13):

Have same error from time to time (when I set install location to "prefer external" in manifest). Just clean and rebuild project. Works for me.

Answer (score 7):

```
tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
```

Try adding this attribute to that permission.

Answer (score 4):

when your add permission in manifest then
in eclipse go to project and clic

1. click on project
2. click on clean project
   that's all

k on clean project

Answer (score 3):

Path In Android Studio in mac:

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections

Expand Android -> Expand Lint -> Expand Correctness

Uncheck the checkbox for *Using system app permission*

Click on "APPLY" -> "OK"

Answer (score 1):

Preferences --> EditorEditor --> Inspections --> Android Lint --> uncheck item Using System app permissio