# Changing Android Device Admin Settings

Tags: android, root, android-source

If you go into your android device to Settings-> Security, under the Device Administration section there are some settings for Verify Apps.

While working on AOSP, I am trying to get some testing software to work. So part of that requires I enable and disable this feature. I already have code to disable some other features, they look like this:

```
    //Allow mock locations
    Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 
            1);

    //Stay on while plugged in
    Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 
            BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB);
```

Note* I am running as root so I can change these settings. So to clarify, my question is how to change the settings Verify Apps, where is that located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `Settings.Global.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE`. It doesn't seem to be up on the documentation site, but you can see it in the source.

Definition:

> [android.provider.Settings.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.Global.0PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE)

Example usage by the default settings app:

> [com.android.settings.SecuritySettings.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/settings/SecuritySettings.java#SecuritySettings.isVerifyAppsEnabled%28%29)

Comment: You got it. I was just looking at the source, and that's exactly it. It's listed as HIDE so you can't access it, but if you can get a copy of the framework jar from the build you can access all that hidden stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks(with upvotes) @Paradopolis and @Geobits with this question and the answer combination. @Geobits gave the correct answer. I'm posting mine, if somebody needs a detailed summarize and a method to get/set that option's status.

`PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE` is first defined at api level 14 with `"verifier_enable"` value under `android.provider.Settings.Secure`.

API level 14(4.0.1_r1):

```
public static final String PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE = "verifier_enable";
```

Its value and defined class changed after API level 17. Its value became `"package_verifier_enable"` under `android.provider.Settings.Global`

API level 17(4.2_r1):

```
public static final String PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE = "package_verifier_enable";
```

`PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE` property is defined public but it is hidden by annotation at its definition. So we can't use it as `Settings.Secure.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE` or `Settings.Global.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE`, but we can use its value.

If anybody needs to determine if package verify is checked/unchecked, or check/uncheck it programmatically can use class below:

```
public abstract class DeviceSettings {

    public enum SettingsCheckStatus {
        CHECKED, UNCHECKED, UNDEFINED
    }

    public static SettingsCheckStatus isVerifyAppsChecked(Context context) {
        // PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE is added after API level 14.
        // Its value changed at API level 17

        int packageVerifierEnabledAsInt = -1;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            packageVerifierEnabledAsInt = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "package_verifier_enable", -1);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            packageVerifierEnabledAsInt = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "verifier_enable", -1);
        } else {
            // No package verification option before API Level 14
        }

        SettingsCheckStatus settingsCheckStatus = SettingsCheckStatus.UNDEFINED;
        switch (packageVerifierEnabledAsInt) {
        case 0:
            settingsCheckStatus = SettingsCheckStatus.UNCHECKED;
            break;
        case 1:
            settingsCheckStatus = SettingsCheckStatus.CHECKED;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return settingsCheckStatus;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param checked
     * @return
     * 
     * You must add <b>android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS</b> to your application's manifest file to use this method. 
     * Keep in mind, lint error checking may show an error on your manifest. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app">See link to solve it.</a> <br>
     * Note that, this method <b>can only work on rooted devices or if your application is going to be a system app.<b>
     * 
     */
    public static boolean setVerifyAppsChecked(Context context, boolean checked) {
        boolean operationCompletedSuccessfully = false;
        int packageVerifierEnabledAsInt = checked ? 1 : 0;
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                operationCompletedSuccessfully = Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), "package_verifier_enable", packageVerifierEnabledAsInt);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                operationCompletedSuccessfully = Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), "verifier_enable", packageVerifierEnabledAsInt);
            } else {
                // No package verification option before API Level 14
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // Your device is not rooted or your app is not a system app.
        }

        return operationCompletedSuccessfully;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Devrim, I've question, posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132239.
I checked with what you suggested here to get if package verified is enabled or disabled from setting. But looks nothing working. It's always return 1. Do you had any work around to get disabled/enabled app verifier?