# How to check if "verify app" is enabled or disabled programmatically

Tags: android, security, verify

I've a security requirement to alert users if google's "verify app" is disabled on app launch. The problem is that I dont know any way to check whether "verify app" is disabled or not.

I tried to use the code below, but it's always returning 1.

```
        int verifierInt = -1;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            verifierInt = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "package_verifier_enable", -1);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            verifierInt = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "verifier_enable", -1);
        } else {
            // No package verification option before API Level 14
        }
        boolean isVerifyAppEnabled = verifierInt == 1;
```

Also, as a requirement, want user to be navigated to the "verifiy app" settings if this feature is disabled.

Comment: Have you disabled Verify apps(under Settings / Google / Security / Verify aps) from the device when you were testing?

Comment: @DevrimTuncer Yes right :) In every case, it's returning to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading preferences, won't help anymore as android don't update preferences now. So basically reading preferences value for google Verify won't work.

Please use below SaftyNet callbacks to verify google protect.

```
SafetyNet.getClient(context)
                .isVerifyAppsEnabled()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SafetyNetApi.VerifyAppsUserResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SafetyNetApi.VerifyAppsUserResponse> task) {
---
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check like this:

```
Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "verifier_verify_adb_installs", -1);
```