# How can i start the uiautomator in android code?

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I want to start an uiautomatorTest program in android code. I use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator runtest AutoRunner.jar -c com.Runner.AutoRunner");
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: You do not have android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT required to call registerUiTestAutomationService from pid=7071, uid=10156
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app/13802178#13802178) It seems, this Permission is only granted to system apps And it seems you may have forgot to add the permission also,

**To add the permission :**

add this directly to your manifest

```
   <uses-permission android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT />
```

**OR**
Inside the service you want the operation to be done like

```
    <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
     </intent-filter>
     . . .
 </service>
```

Have a brief look at [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html)

Comment: sorry , I add   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT" /> in manfest.xml, it seems that the problems also exists

Comment: @dongzhetai It seems, this Permission is only granted to system apps. Have a look at the discussion. Link is at my edited answer.

Comment: @dongzhetai plz let me know if you solved the issue in future !!

Comment: OK，I havent solved now,and will tell you if I solved now