# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.geofences from uid 10049 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION

Tags: android, geolocation, android-permissions

I'm working on GPS location related App, i'm faceing below issue while genarating Mock Location points to App for testing.

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.geofences from uid 10049 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We need to do two steps:

**Step 1:**
Give a permission in Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

**Step 2:**
In your real device,

Go to Setting --> Developer option --> Mock location app option and 
select your app for testing.

Mock location works fine... :)

Thanks,

Comment: yes security exceptions are always permission releated exception in android

Comment: @Mrinmoy, I was spend whole a day for the second step, i given permission in manifest file but i didn't followed second step. finally i got solution.

Comment: There is an error which is described and solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app

Comment: Anyway, I still get the error.

Comment: I mean in the emulator, it still gave an error. I fixed it with running this lines in the terminal: "cd %LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools" and "adb shell appops set <uid printed in previous error> android:mock_location allow"