# Broadcast receiver. I want to move to another activity through a broadcast receiver after the charger is disconnected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a university project where I have to make a charger alarm. I select a ringtone, enter a pin, then plug in a charger. When I plug out, it moves to another activity where the phone starts ringing, the screen is locked and can only proceed if provided a correct pin code.

I'm stuck at the point where I have to move from one activity to another when the charger disconnects.

My code is not working. This is the receiver in the manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$PowerConnectionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is the broadcast receiver I made in the MainActivity:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Toast.makeText(context, "The device is not charging", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,setter.class);
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see:

> You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only
>   by explicitly registering for it with...

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

And did you set the corresponding permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
```

Comment: I'm new to java/android studio. Could you kindly share an implementation of intent register receiver?

Comment: No i did not add this permission. I'll add it.

Comment: You will get it :-) just call `registerReceiver(yourBroadcastReceiver, yourIntentFilter);` inside your activity. Use Logcat to verify if you receive the action (when the charger get's disconnected). If so, continue with the intent.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>

Comment: on this permission it is giving me an error that it only allows system apps to use this.

Comment: Did you implement the receiver in your java code? Let's try first without setting the permission. Otherwise you can fix the error described here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app

Comment: wow ... it worked ... but it only disconnects the charger. I made a new intent inside broadcast receiver to move to another activity. The app crashed.

Comment: should I put the intent in try catch?

Comment: Nice! Yes, put it on the try catch and look what logcat says.. use the catch bock to call e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 0):

Your intent has not correct parameters.

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,setter.class);
```

Change should be:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class)
```

Make sure your `<receiver></receiver>` tags are out of the activity tag in Manifest. Place them in application level.

Comment: does `onReceived()` ever get called?

Comment: Probably not. I've tried setting text to a TextView inside onReceive(). The textView doesn't change. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm new to android studio and java so I'm not sure what's the problem with it. It seems fine.

Comment: I got the weirdest project and my instructor made it up on the spot while assigning it to me. I have to present it on Thursday and I've been stuck on it for days.